# Query nested object in spring mongo db repository

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

i'm new to spring data and mongo db i have a mongo collection like these

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59cb8821a1a7963044bfe055"), "_class" : "com.test.User", "vehicle" : [ { "name" : "bus", "color" : "blue" } ], "totalcount" : 1,  "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-09-27T11:14:41.576Z"), "createdBy" : "Admin"}
```

i have tried the below method to pull the data

```
@Query("{Vehicle.name : ?0}")
public List<User> findByVehicleName(String name);
```

And i'm getting only "Vehicle" object. i want to pull out "_id" , "vehicle" object like (name,color) and "createdDate", "createdBy" columns as well..Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still little unclear what exactly is the  problem. Should be `@Query("{vehicle.name : ?0}")` . Actually it should work without the @Query annotation too.  Is mapping not working for you ? Can you add User pojo to the post ?

Comment: @Document(collection="User")
public class User{
List<Vehicle> vehicle;

public void setVehicle(List<Vehicle> vehicle) {
  this.vehicle = vehicle;
 }
 
 public List<Vehicle> getVehicle() {
  return vehicle;
 }
 ...
}    Yes it is @Query("{vehicle.name:?0}") typo there..

Comment: I don't see rest of the fields in your pojo. Can you add the fields and spring will map correctly ?

Comment: Sorry i was getting entire list from spring data. But i here is what i'm doing in java8 this is getting vehicle list

List<User> userlist = repository.findByVehicleName(String name);
List<vehicle> vehiclelist = userlist.stream().flatMap(vehicle->vehicle.getVehicles().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());

,But i want to pull the "_id","totalcount", "createdDate" ,
"createdBy" also. i'm new to java 8 any help will be appreciated.